# how to set a table column to a specific value based on matching data to another table

Tags: mysql

I want to insert a character in a column in table 1 if the first name and last name in table 1 match the first name and last name in table 2.
Table 2 contains only names. Table 1 has several columns, one of which I want to update. Both are in name order.

I tried the following code based on several searches but it gives a syntax error.

```
update table t1, table t2
set t1.col = "J"
where t1.fname = t2.fname and t1.lname = t2.lname;
```

> Error 1064 (42000) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'table t1, table t2 set t1.col = "J" where t1.fname
>   = t2.fname' at line 1

Comment: Although it is not the proper way to update, you should use a join, your code would work if you did not write `table`, but: `update t1, t2
set t1.col = "J"
where t1.fname = t2.fname and t1.lname = t2.lname;`

Comment: worked great,,,thanks forpas

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the join, like this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.fname = t2.fname and t1.lname = t2.lname
SET col = "J"
```